# Automatic email each time change is made in GIT repo

Tags: git, email, githooks

I want to know if there is a way I can have an automatic email sent out after a person makes a commit in a git repo. Each time somebody pushes something into the repo, I would like to have an automatic email sent out to an email list I have specified.
Thank you.

Comment: To answer your question, you should provide some more details: where is your remote repo is hosted (GitHub, bit bucket, your server - which OS?)

Comment: It's hosted on my server and I am using Linux.

Comment: I'll update my answer in a min

Answer (score 1):

I point you to this tutorial where they go into detail on setting up an email list to be notified on git changes  http://www.systutorials.com/1473/setting-up-git-commit-email-notification/

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Please look at my comment (in your question).
2. Generally, there's git hooks for each operation, such as push, pull etc. You can "register" to those hooks and perform any operation you like (sending an email for example)

EDIT:
in your git bare repository, look for the 'hooks' directory (should be in .git/hooks). You might see some commented example there but the idea is that each hook (event) is represented by a script file (the filename telling you which hook it is). In this script file you can do whatever you like. I (for example) used it to trigger my jenkins to start a new build. You can use it for sending an email.

more info:
[Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and [5 Ways to Send Email From Linux Command Line](http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/#)

If it solved your problem please accept this answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into that.

Comment: @Leena I've edit the answer for you. If it solve your problem - please accept it :-)